# Vue v-model not detecting chrome auto-completion

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, vuejs2

This only seems to be an issue with Chrome because I am not seeing this issue in Firefox. I am using Vue 2.6.11, and have a very simple login page:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      id="username"
      :value="username_field"
      @input="user_field_change"
      type="text"
      autocomplete="username"
    />
    <input
      id="password"
      v-model="password_field"
      type="password"
      autocomplete="current-password"
    />
    <div>v-model of user: {{ username_field }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Login",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      username_field: null,
      password_field: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    user_field_change(event) {
      this.username_field = event.target.value;
      console.log(`user change: ${this.username_field}`);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

It has username and password inputs which have been targeted for autocomplete. However, I am seeing that Chrome is autocompleting them but the v-model is NOT being updated as the v-model output is not showing the username and the console is not logged. Once I click on something else and the input loses focus, the v-model is updated and a console log is output. See this gif:

[image]

I have tried placing a "name" attribute on the inputs as some google searches suggest, but it has not worked.

Why is this happening, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in [codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JjRrEZE).

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have this problem too.

Comment: This is a security feature - https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7058 and  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1166619